# time between two places using public transport

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there some Google Maps API for Android that could return time between two places using public transport (and walking)? Something like Google Maps does when selecting public transit, but I'm interested only in times.

Also, is there way on Android to get list of nearest transit stops (from given location, not necessary phone)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer google direction API .it provide all types of details. it gives a response based on JSON or xml. if you refer json then pass in url json.

used retrofit for getting direction API response and bind getting data according to google map.

below url is give all data..

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=ahmedabad&destination=faizbad&mode=transit&language=gu&key=AIzaSyCMNK9WsbC2vgvMB_trDOjTs2QUvOd7ECw

more information u can refer below link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#TravelModes

Answer (score 0):

Hi below is the link which helps you for which you want

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Where you find request URL throw which you can find distance or time duration between tow place using different-different parameter
Below is the sample URL for use
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/outputFormat?parameters

You need to pass your API key in parameter compulsory.